# OpenMP with OCAML

Tags: multithreading, ocaml, openmp, parallel-processing

Does anyone know if it's possible use OpenMP with OCaml source code?

Or another application/ambient of work, compatible with OCaml, that allows me to run parallel programs that exploit multiple cores?

If yes, how? Have you got an easy example?

Answer (score 7):

Currently there is [OC4MC](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocmc/web/) (ocaml 4 multi-core) to perform shared memory multi-processing. I have not used the project, but there are fairly recent updates, so I can only assume the project is still moving forward.

*[JOCAML](http://jocaml.inria.fr/) is another concurrent extension to ocaml implementing the join calculus. I have also not used this project, but their site is updated to mention ocaml 3.12, which came out fairly recently.* Disregard; see comment.

If you can pry yourself away from the openMP paradigm, then there are [ocaml bindings for mpi](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/ocamlmpi/). I use this project, and have not had problems with it, and it's pretty easy to use if you are familiar with MPI.

Lastly, some (possibly unmaintained) packages pertaining to multi-core / parallel processing can be found on the [ocaml hump](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=77).

Comment: jocaml will not let you "exploit multiple cores" - not more than the ocaml itself

Comment: I try to install OC4MC but i have, how result, this error : 

gcc -O -I../runtime/asmrun -I../runtime/byterun -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DNATIVE_CODE -DTARGET_i386 -DSYS_linux_elf -c posix.c
posix.c: In function ‘caml_thread_initialize’:
posix.c:215: error: ‘caml_main_thread_struct’ undeclared (first use in this function)
posix.c:215: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
posix.c:215: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [posix_n.o] Error 1
Error when executing `make libthreadsnat.a'              How can i do? thank you !! :)